# Call screen on button click?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a mainscreen with a few buttons in it and I'm trying to assiciate each button with a screen call. I can't get it to work though. I created the button with the layout painter but I don't see how to make it functional.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- open the screen painter
- double click on the button
- enter a Function Code (the field is above "Context Menu Form")

now that your button has a function code it will fire this OK-Code and the dynpros "PROCESS AFTER INPUT" will be run. add a PAI module to the dynpro and in the module you could for example make the following coding:

```
case sy-ucomm. " the ok code

  when 'your_buttons_function_code_here'.
    call screen YOUR_SCREEN_NUMBER_HERE.

  when others. 
    " DO NOTHING

endcase.
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this but for some reason nothing is happening when I click the button. I am calling the module on the PAI part of the screen. And I'm also clearing the ok_code in the PBO part. Any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you first enable the debuger (enter /h in the transaction field) and then click on the button? what's the value of the sy-ucomm variable?

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but it was on my end, your code works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must create a screen & perform CALL SCREEN inside that event. There's a concept called PAO & PBO. You may refer that too. Few links for your reference..

- http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9f/dbab2935c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm
- http://www.abapprogramming.net/2008/04/sap-abap-syntax-for-call-screen.html